# back button causing hash change page trap javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I store my webpage info in the URL hash, including page number. In order to ensure the page does not exceed the total pages I added this condition. assuming total pages = 10

```
//get page value from URL 
function getParams(val){
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp('[#|&]' + val + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.hash)||[,''])[1]
      );
   }


var totalPages = 10;

   $(window).on('hashchange',function(){
   if(getParams('page') > totalPages){
      window.location = "#page=1";
   } 
});
```

the problem is that if the page loads from another time where the total pages were more:

```
www.website.com#page=11
```

it redirects to page 1, but then if the user navigates back, it goes back to page 11 for an instant then redirects back to page 1 and gets trapped in that cycle, making it impossible for the user to navigate back. is there any way to prevent this problem? thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem before, use `window.location.replace(url)` instead of  `window.location = url;` so that the previous page will not be saved in the session history.